# Storing value and then sending everything in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I am working in Node-red built on node js
I was trying to create one node which will store all inputs from different function node and then will send them all to next node.
in Node-RED each msg process once and it is sent and the msg process is asynchronous by property.

Documentation : http://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/node-js.html

This is node-RED wiring screenshot:

[image]

There are two functions going to a concatenation node
The concatenation node code is:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function LowerCaseNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        var node = this;
        this.on('input', function(msg) {
        var abc = [];
        abc.push(msg.payload);
            node.send(msg);
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("lower-case",LowerCaseNode);
}
```

the output what I am getting in debug tab is:

[image]

The output I wanted in debug tab is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your concat node has no way of knowing which function node the incoming message came from, there is no information about the source passed with a message.

The best you could do is set a different topic field in each function node and use this to distinguish inputs.

Also this probably doen't need to be a separate node, you should be able to implement it as a function node and make use of the `context` variable.

Comment: But if for a source which is not a function or say it is not only a function . msg may come from anywhere. I just have to concatenate say n number of msg then how to do that. I am not able to do that. I want to do with my own custom node.not with a function node. Please help me out.